# Relationship Conflict with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I want to send emails after a record has been saved to a 'lesson hours' table. I am getting very odd behavior however. 
In my test pages I have discovered that the error (trying to get property of a non object) seems to happen based on the number of items I have in the 'Packages' table. If I have two packages, the MessageSent Event fires to send the email once. After that the error(s) begin. (Sometimes the error is 'Call to member function getFullName(lessonhours_id)' comes up.) If I have 4 packages, I can send 3 emails etc...
The records get inserted into the database except for the log file which is inserted when the MessageSent Event fires as well. It seems that there is some kind of relationship glitch as somehow the related properties seem to be invisible after a couple of records have been created. I have a 1 to many relationship with Packages and Lessonhours. I can see the relationship work when I use 'Tinker'. Any insights would be appreciated.

Tinker code:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.7.2 (PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $les = App\Lessonhours::first();
=> App\Lessonhours {#662
     id: 1,
     created_at: "2016-11-03 13:16:42",
     updated_at: "2016-11-03 13:16:42",
     players_id: 1,
     packages_id: 1,
     signup_date: "2016-09-06",
   }
>>> $les = App\Lessonhours::first();
=> App\Lessonhours {#664
     id: 1,
     created_at: "2016-11-03 13:16:42",
     updated_at: "2016-11-03 13:16:42",
     players_id: 1,
     packages_id: 1,
     signup_date: "2016-09-06",
   }
>>> $les->players->getFullName($les->players_id)
=> "Girltest Testfam"
>>> $les->packages->name
=> "04 Pack Pvt"
>>>
```

Lessonhours Model:

```
  <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Lessonhours extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array('signup_date', 'players_id', 'packages_id');

    public $table = "lessonhours";

    public function players()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Players', 'id');
    }

    public function packages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Packages', 'id');
    }

    public function hoursused()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Hoursused', 'lessonhours_id');
    }

    protected $dates = ['signup_date'];


}
```

Packages Model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Packages extends Model
{
    public $table = "packages";
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'cost', 'numberofhours', 'type'];

    public function lessonhours()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Lessonhours', 'packages_id');
    }
}
```

Event MessageSent:

```
   use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\Lessonhours;

class MessageSent extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Lessonhours $lessonhours)
    {

        $this->lessonhours = $lessonhours; 
        $this->player = $lessonhours->players->getFullName($lessonhours-   >players_id);
        $this->email = $lessonhours->players->family->email;
        $this->package = $lessonhours->packages->name;
    }
```

Listener:

```
 public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{
    $lessonhours = $event->lessonhours;
    $player = $event->player;
    $email = $event->email;
    $package = $event->package;

    Mail::send('admin.email.lessonhoursnotification', ['name' => $lessonhours], function($message) use ($player, $email, $package){

        $message->from('test@test.com', 'Lesson Mgmt');
        $message->to($email, $player);
        $message->subject('Lesson Package Update');

    });
}
```

[First Insert with Two Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqapQ.png)

[Error thrown on the new record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaMid.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is in your `Lessonhours` model.  The 2nd parameter of `belongsTo()` should be the column that references the parent's key on the current table. So it should be:

```
public function players()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Players', 'players_id');
}

public function packages()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Packages', 'packages_id');
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: I guess It really threw me since whenever I reset the database, the first couple of records would work depending on how many packages I seeded. Thanks for the help. The emails are sending now.